# We need tag wiki wordings

Tags: discussion

A quick look at the [tags](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags) will show that very few have a tag wiki (the brief wording below a tag that explains what it is for). Even if you don't have access to edit these, you have access to suggest edits to these, which is still very helpful (just click on the tag and you will see a link to create a tag wiki, which need only be a sentence or two).

The sooner we get these completed, the less chance there will be of conflicting use of tags which will be a pain to clear up later. Better to have something written so it is explicit, then if there is disagreement it will be known and can be discussed. If you're really not sure which way to describe a particular tag, raise a meta question. Otherwise, just go ahead and write the tag wiki excerpt - it will be edited again in future if necessary.

I recommend just focusing on the excerpts for now (a few sentences to summarise). The longer full wording can be filled in later (feel free to do these too - I just want to prioritise the excerpts first as they are quick to complete).

Comment: Maybe when [this](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/115/98) problem is resolved, there will be more non-empty tag wikis.

Comment: @celtschk thanks for highlighting that... I hope the review of the private beta and how much we've achieved will take into account that problem.

Comment: @celtschk some of the edits I made have shown up now so it looks like the problem may be fixed. Time to get editing... :)

Comment: I did loads last week but I must have had a certain percentage declined. I'm not allowed to add any more :(

Answer (score 6):

I've been doing this some, and others have to. But I agree that we need to focus on it more. I suggest that when people pick a tag to favorite, they also go an update the tag wiki for that tag. If you create a new tag in a question, you should also go update the excerpt, if not the full tag. This will help others make sure your question actually fits the tag.